# Boundedness properties of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ be an unbounded simply connected domain distinct from $\mathbb{C}$ and let $f\in H(D)$ be a bounded function such that $|f|\leq M$ on $\partial D$. Prove that $|f|\leq M$ on $D$.

The hint says to consider the function $\frac{f(z)^n}{z-a}$ with $a\notin D$ and to apply the maximum modulus principle but I'm not really convince of why we should consider such a function.

I thought of using the fact that every open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ has an exhaustion and then argue that on each compact set, $f$ must attain its maximum on the boundary and thus at the limit attain its maximum on the boundary of $D$ but I really would like to understand more the hint.

Also, I would like to know if there is an equivalent statement of the MMP for functions defined on the riemann sphere. My idea is the following : this unbounded subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is bounded on $S^2$ so maybe we could apply the MMP to $f$ as a function living on the riemann sphere.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wlog $| f (z)| \le 1$ on $\partial D.$ It is given, that $| f (z)| \le M<\infty$ in $D$, so we have to prove that $| f (z_0)|\le 1$ for every $z_0 \in D.$ I know a proof for $D=\{\text{Re}z>0\}$, which I think can be extended (easily?) to the general case.

Set $h(z)=\frac{f(z)^n}{z+1}$. Then, $|h(z)| \le 1$ on $\{\text{Re}z=0\}$ and $|h(z)|\le M^n/R$ for all $z \in D$ such that $|z| = R.$ So, $|h(z)|\le \max(1, M^n/R)$ on the boundary of $D_R =\{z \in D : |z| ≤ R\}.$

Now then, if $R > M^n$, and $z_0\in D_R$ then $|h(z)|\le 1$ on $\partial D_R$,and now we can apply the Maximum Modulus Theorem to say that  $|h(z_0)|\le 1.$

But then, $|f(z_0)|\le |z_0+1|^{|/n}$, and we obtain the result letting $n\to\infty.$

Comment: So basically here it is assumed that $f$ is continuous on the boundary; the result is actually true if it is known only that limsup$|f| \leq M$ on the boundary except at finitely many points, $f$ is analytic and bounded in $D$ but no other condition except the limsup above at the boundary and $D$ doesn't need to be simply connected, only that its complement is infinite.